# python tkinter text widget testing

Tags: python, unit-testing, tkinter

I need to test the text widget, or rather compare the tag that appears for the character in the text line, if the user pressed the desired button, this is in the key_type () function.
Why the character isn't inserted when you call event_generate?

```
import tkinter as tkinter
import unittest
from tkinter import *
import main

class MyGUI(tkinter.Frame):
    def __init__(self, top, **kw):
        super().__init__(top, **kw)
        self.button1 = Button(self, text="Играть",command=lambda: main.command())
        self.button2 = Button(self, text="Выйти",command=lambda: main.command2())
        self.button1.pack()
        self.button2.pack()
        test_text = "Avd"
        self.text_widget = Text(self, height=10, width=100,
                           padx=20, pady=20, font=("Arial ", 16))
        self.text_widget.insert(END, test_text)
        self.text_widget.configure(state="disabled")
        self.text_widget.tag_config("correct", background="green", foreground="white")
        self.text_widget.tag_config("wrong", background="red", foreground="white")

        self.text_widget.bind("<KeyPress>", main.key_type)
        self.text_widget.focus()
        self.text_widget.pack()
class TKinterTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.top = Toplevel()
        self.root2 = Tk()

    def tearDown(self):
        if self.top:
            self.top.destroy()
        if self.root2:
            self.root2.destroy()

    def test_enter1(self):
        v = MyGUI(self.top)
        v.button2.event_generate('<Button-1>')
        self.assertTrue(v.button1.winfo_exists())

    def test_enter2(self):
        v = MyGUI(self.top)
        v.button2.event_generate('<Button-1>')
        self.assertTrue(v.button2.winfo_exists())
        v.text_widget.focus_set()
        v.after(100, lambda: self.root2.event_generate('A'))
        self.assertEqual("correct",v.text_widget.tag_names(1.0))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

```
def key_type(e):
    if e.keycode != 16:
        global pos, text_widget, b, mistakes, correct_presses
        if (test_text[pos] != e.char):
            text_widget.tag_add("wrong", str(1) + "." + str(b))
            mistakes += 1
        if (test_text[pos] == e.char):
            text_widget.tag_add("correct", str(1) + "." + str(b))
            correct_presses += 1
        b += 1
        pos += 1
```

run test:
'correct' != ()

Comment: @PCM,why? I need to compare tag names

Comment: Try looking at `tk.Text.tag_names` and `tk.Text.tag_ranges`.  The first will give a tuple of names used in a text widget and the second returns the range of characters the named tag applies too.

Comment: @Tls Chris it seems to me that this is not the problem, but that 'v.text_widget.event_generate ('A') ' does not write A

Comment: Your question needs to be more focused. Are you asking why the character isn't inserted when you call `event_generate`, or are you asking how to get the tag of the inserted character?

Comment: @Bryan Oakley, why the character isn't inserted when you call event_generate

Comment: I recommend you reduce the code down to a [mcve]. For example, we don't need a `MyGUI1` and `MyGUI2`. Your code actually creates three separate windows, but you only need one to learn about generating events in a text widget. You also don't need such a complicated `key_type` - just validating that the text was inserted should only take a couple of lines of code.